# How to remove Cyanogenmod from Sony Xperia Z?

Tags: cyanogenmod, sony-xperia-z, flashtool

I've got an old Sony Xperia Z running Cyanogenmod which is pretty unstable.

I'd like to remove Cyanogenmod & do a factory reset to the default Sony Xperia Z ROM. It doesn't need to do much - just run Spotify & Google Maps in our car.

However flashing a Sony Phone with a factory ROM requires a special tool ([FlashTool](http://www.flashtool.net/index.php)) & a special file format (FTF).

Running FlashTool on Ubuntu 16.04 my phone connects in flash mode, but then reboots into Cyanogenmod after the "Preparing the files for flashing" step. I had assumed this was something to do with Cyanogenmod.

```
INFO  - Device connected in flash mode
INFO  - Selected Bundle for Sony Xperia Z(C6603). FW release : 10.5.A.0.230. Customization : C6603_1270-4066
INFO  - Preparing files for flashing
INFO  - Device disconnected
```

How do remove Cyanogenmod from a Sony Xperia Z & restore it to it's factory ROM?

If that isn't possible what can I replace Cyanogenmod with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such thing as "CM bootloader" - a CM installation only writes a new `/boot` (kernel) and `/system`.

Since you are explicitly looking to return to stock, FlashTool is still your best bet. Find the latest stock ROM for your variant and region using [XperiFirm](https://forum.xda-developers.com/crossdevice-dev/sony/pc-xperifirm-xperia-firmware-downloader-t2834142), generate a `.ftf` format file with what you downloaded using Flashtool with the guide [here](http://www.xperiablog.net/2014/08/16/create-your-own-ftf-firmware-files-using-xperifirm-and-flashtool-guide/), then flash away.

Comment: Sorry, I think I'm getting confused between the bootloader & Cyanogenmod recovery. When I use Flashtool & try to flash it the phone reboots, which I thought was Cyanogenmod behaviour.

Comment: Did you actually put the phone into download mode as per Flashtool instructions?

Comment: I finally succeeded by using Windows 10 + "Emma" the Sony Flash Tool. It was super easy. So I'll put my previous issues down to Ubuntu rather than phone weirdness.

Comment: Didn't even see you were using Ubuntu... Another reason why I always tinker with my phones under WIndows.